# Как преобразовать полученные координаты яндекс.карты в адрес?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Использую готовый калькулятор доставки. После построения маршрута в данный момент в input попадают координаты. Подскажите как геокодировать координаты перед вставкой в input адресом вида: Город, улица, дом?

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
  // Стоимость за километр.
    DELIVERY_TARIFF = 100,
  // Минимальная стоимость.
        MINIMUM_COST = 500,
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [43.801946, 131.950582],
            zoom: 16,
            controls: []
        }),
    // Создадим панель маршрутизации.
        routePanelControl = new ymaps.control.RoutePanel({
            options: {
                // Добавим заголовок панели.
                showHeader: true,
                title: 'Расчёт перевозок',
    autofocus: false
            }
        }),
        zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({
            options: {
                size: 'small',
                float: 'none',
                position: {
                    bottom: 145,
                    right: 10
                }
            }
        });
 
    // Пользователь сможет построить только автомобильный маршрут.
    routePanelControl.routePanel.options.set({
        types: {auto: true}
    });
    myMap.controls.add(routePanelControl).add(zoomControl);

    // Получим ссылку на маршрут.
    routePanelControl.routePanel.getRouteAsync().then(function (route) {

        // Зададим максимально допустимое число маршрутов, возвращаемых мультимаршрутизатором.
        route.model.setParams({results: 1}, true);
  
        // Повесим обработчик на событие построения маршрута.
        route.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function () {

            var activeRoute = route.getActiveRoute();  
     
            if (activeRoute) {
                // Получим протяженность маршрута.
                var length = route.getActiveRoute().properties.get("distance");
                
    //Вычисляем координаты
    var roadAid = routePanelControl.routePanel.state.get("from");  
    document.querySelector('#roadA').value = roadAid;   
     

    var roadBid = routePanelControl.routePanel.state.get("to");     
    document.querySelector('#roadB').value = roadBid;
   // Вычислим стоимость доставки.
                    price = calculate(Math.round(length.value / 1000)),
    
                // Создадим макет содержимого балуна маршрута.
                    balloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                        '<span>Расстояние: ' + length.text + '.</span><br/>' +
                        '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Стоимость доставки: ' + price + ' р.</span>');
                // Зададим этот макет для содержимого балуна.
                route.options.set('routeBalloonContentLayout', balloonContentLayout);
                // Откроем балун.
                activeRoute.balloon.open();
            }
   
        });

    });
 window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    // Функция, вычисляющая стоимость доставки.
    function calculate(routeLength) {
        return Math.max(routeLength * DELIVERY_TARIFF, MINIMUM_COST);
    }
}
```

```css
#map {
    height:300px ;
    width:515px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div class="form-group maps">
 <div class="log-form-group ">
 <label class="what-road_label" for="roadA"></label>
 <input class="what-road" id="roadA" type="text" name="field" placeholder="Откуда">        
</div>
<div class="log-form-group">
 <label class="what-road_label" for="roadB"></label>
 <input class="what-road" id="roadB" type="text" name="field" placeholder="Куда">        
</div>       
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу на свой вопрос. 
Для вывода данных *Россия, Регион, Город, Улица, Дом*

```
var myCoordsfrom = [roadAid];       
var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(myCoordsfrom);
myGeocoder.then(
    function (res) {
        var nearest = res.geoObjects.get(0);
        var name = nearest.properties.get('text');              
        document.querySelector('#roadA').value = name;
    },
    function (err) {
        alert('Ошибка');
    }
);
```

Для вывода других данных, к примеру только *Россия, Регион, Город* дописываем вид топонома

```
var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(myCoordsfrom, {kind: 'street'});
```

Про все варианты можно посмотреть [тут](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/reference/kind-docpage/).

Для вывода *всего, что есть*
вместо:

```
var name = nearest.properties.get('text');
```

пишем:

```
var name = nearest.properties.getAll;
```

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте документацию API Яндекс.Карт. Я уверен, что там есть функция преобразования координат в адрес. Потом просто через ajax обратитесь, и получите ответ. Потом просто js вставляете данные в input. (Надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос)

Comment: Я тоже уверен, что там есть, но я не нашел, что мне нужно. Мне нужно, чтобы в самом скрипте геокодировать координаты, которые находятся в переменных roadAid, roadBid и передать уже в виде адреса в input

Comment: Прошу. https://toster.ru/q/489732

Comment: Читал и видел это пост. Но в моем вопросе я  не знаю как сделать.